# How get driver instance in listener class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, listener

I have a test class that runs by getting driver parameters from TestNG file. Here's the flow of the framework.

`<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>` is provided in TestNG file.

This is used by **logintest** class.

```
public class LoginLogoutTest extends Base{
  @Test
  @Parameters("browser")
  public void initializeBrowser(String browser) throws IOException{
      super.initializeBrowser(browser);
      driver.get("https://www.google.com")
      Assert.assertEquals(xpath_to_get_header, "Invalid_header_name");
  }
```

**initializeBrowser** is declared in Base class.

```
public class Base {
public WebDriver driver;

public void initializeBrowser(String browser) throws IOException {
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", currentDir + "\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } 
     else { //do something }
```

Now, how can i implement listener class so that it takes screenshot on failure? This is how i tried, but i don't know how to get driver instance from my **logintest** class.

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    File Src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(Src, new File("C://test//" + result + "screen.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Quick answer***

*You need to add listener tag inside TestNG.xml. Please have a look at below screenshot for reference*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the listener class methods on your test class by adding a parameter of `<listener>` in your testng class.

So, lets say the class name where you have written your `onTestFailure(ITestResult result)` is `ListenerClass` and this class is implementing the `ITestListener`, so in this case you just need to mention the listener class name in the testng file and it will apply all the methods mention in your listener class to your test class.

Implementation would be something like:

Listener Class:

```
public class ListenerClass implements ITestListener{

@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
File Src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
try {
    FileUtils.copyFile(Src, new File("C://test//" + result + "screen.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Testng file:

```
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="tests" preserve-order="true">

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="packageName.ListenerClass"></listener> (Add your listener class path here)
</listeners>

    <test name="Testing" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="packageName.LoginLogoutTest"/> (Add your test class path here)
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Listners class we get instance of any object with ItestResult as below

inside listners class we act up on onTestfailure

```java
public coid onTestfailure(ItestResult result){
    
 Webdriver driver; 

driver=(WebDriver)result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getDeclaredField("driver").get(result.getInatnce())

//method from your utility class

getScrrensot(result.getMethod().getMethodName(),driver)
}
```